# ETL using confluent kafka connect

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-kafka-connect

We have a use case where we are using Kafka connect to Source and Sink data. Its like a typical ETL.

We want to understand if Kafka connect can identify the delta changes between previous streams. i.e. we want to send only the changed data to client and not the whole table or view. Also, we prefer not to execute explicit code to identify changes via a query on source and destination DB.

Is there any preferred approach towards it?

Answer (score 2):

As gasparms said, use a CDC tool to pull all change events from your database. You can then use Kafka Streams or KSQL to filter, join, and aggregate as required by your ETL.

What's your source system that you want to get data from? For Oracle (and several other sources), as of GoldenGate 12.3.1 they actually bundle the Kafka Connect handler as part of the [download](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/middleware/goldengate/downloads/index.html) itself. You also have other options such as DBVisit.

For open-source DBs then Debezium definitely fits the bill, and there is a nice [tutorial here](http://debezium.io/blog/2017/09/25/streaming-to-another-database/).

Answer (score 1):

Have you looked a [CDC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Change_data_capture) (Change Data Capture) approach. There are several [connectors](https://www.confluent.io/product/connectors/) that read a commit log or similar in a database and stream events. Using these events you'll get every change in a table.

**Examples**

> Oracle Golden Gate -
>   http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/middleware/goldengate/oracle-goldengate-exchange-3805527.html
>
> Postgres - https://github.com/debezium
>
> MySQL - https://github.com/debezium